# loading gif is not working when binding a json data to jquery datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

here we are not using any ajax calls just binding a json object to the datatable
below is the code i'm using

```
$(".loading").show();
$('#myTable').DataTable().destroy();

    var dataTable = $('#myTable').DataTable({

        data: passeddata,
        dom: 'lBfrtip',
                            buttons: [{ extend: 'excel', text: 'Export to Excel', filename: 'Global Credit Analysis Report' }],
                            "lengthMenu": [[100, 200, 300, 500], [100, 200, 300, 500]],
        deferRender: true,
        "scrollY": '60vh',
        "scrollX": true,


order: [[6, 'asc']],
        columns: [

            { "data": "GFS_x0020_Region","defaultContent": "" },
            { "data": "Focal_x0020_Point_x0020_of_x0020.Title","defaultContent": ""},
            { "data": "Preparer_x0020_Email.Title","defaultContent": ""},
            { "data": "RequesterFullName","defaultContent": "" },
            { "data": "RequestorsOrganization","defaultContent": "" }


        ]
    });


    dataTable.columns.adjust();
$(".loading").hide();
```

Comment: you want to block the screen or just table?

Comment: block the enitre page

Answer (score 0):

there is a complete callback of datatable

```
$('#myTable').dataTable( {
   . . .
  "initComplete": function( settings, json ) {
    $('.loading').hide();
  }
} );
```

The issue is datatable takes time to load everything, but the code is executed already, so your loading appears and then disappear quickly. 
You could use wait or delay but thats not ideal.